# Start border from the text in html table

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;padding-left:12.4em;" bordercolor="F0C347">                                 
 <tbody>
    <tr>                      
        <td><b>Assert Name </b></td>             
        <td><b>Expected</b></td>    
        <td><b>Actual</b></td>           
         <td><b>Assert Expression</b></td>  
    </tr>       
    <tr>            
         <td>Name</td>            
          <td> true</td>    
           <td> true</td> 
           <td>assert.equal(true,spy.calledOnce);</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The output looks like this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/babtb2uy/1/).

In the left hand side, I can the see border is taking up white spaces, rather than that it would be great, if the border starts from `Assert Name` only.

How should I do that?

Note: I want the padding to be present.

Comment: Need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/babtb2uy/2/)?

Comment: remove the padding http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/babtb2uy/3/

Comment: @batman if u need the padding , let me just edit my answer

Comment: you need padding or margin http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/babtb2uy/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table has a lot of extra padding. Remove it and it should work.

EDIT:I think you are looking for margin and not padding , please use those words properly.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;margin-left:12.4em;" bordercolor="F0C347" >                                 
 <tbody>
    <tr>                      
        <td><b>Assert Name </b></td>             
        <td><b>Expected</b></td>    
        <td><b>Actual</b></td>           
         <td><b>Assert Expression</b></td>  
    </tr>       
    <tr>            
         <td>Name</td>            
          <td> true</td>    
           <td> true</td> 
           <td>assert.equal(true,spy.calledOnce);</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

*Updated Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/babtb2uy/6/*

Answer (score -1):

Please remove padding-left:12.4em; from inline style : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/babtb2uy/1/)

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;" bordercolor="F0C347">
```

Comment: just give margin-left:12.4em  in place of padding  http://jsfiddle.net/babtb2uy/1/

Answer (score -3):

set

> padding-left:0em

That's it